# Convert the concrete syntax of expression from ML to Java

Tags: java, syntax, semantics, ml, bnf

I have the following 2 concrete syntax of expression and declaration in ML, I'm not familiar with ML, so I am just wondering if anyone can help me to convert it in Java, thanks very much

```
Exp::= 
       Ide |
       "if" Exp "then" Exp "else" Exp |
       "fun" "(" Ide ")" Exp |
       Exp "(" Exp ")" |
       "let" Decl "in" Exp |
       "(" Exp ")"

Decl ::=
       Ide "=" Exp | 
       Decl "then" Decl | 
       "rec" Decl | 
       "(" Decl ")"
```

Comment: What do you want to "convert"? That's a BNF grammar of something vaguely ML-like, not a program.